# How to debug dockerised .net core app with dotnet watch run

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing a .net core app, within a linux based docker container, and I want to be able to both debug it in Visual Studio 2019 and have fast reloading for the sweetest possible development experience.  Is this combination possible? If so, how?

Thanks.